# Update table with join and if does not exists then NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a Master table with pid_name column varchar(40) and I want to update that pid_name colulmn with pname from another table processes.
 Processes table has 2 column pid and pname with 100 distinct rows.
 pid from master table has more than 50K distinct values for pid_name. I want to update pid_name with all values from processes table and NULL which does not exists in processes table.
I am using Redshift Database. Thanks in advance
Sample Data

> Master Table before update
>   `ID   Pid_name`
>   `1    abc`
>   `2    def`
>   `3    ghi`
>   processes table
>   `pid   pname`
>   `abc   Process_1`
>   `def   Process_2`
>   Expected output in Master table after update
>   `ID   Pid_name`
>   `1    Process_1`
>   `2    Process_2`
>   `3    NULL`    (Since it does not exist in processes table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE master
SET pid_name =
    (SELECT pname
     FROM processes p
     WHERE p.pid = master.pid_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Laurenz!
But this will not update my pid_name to null, if pid does not exists in processes table.

Comment: Perfect! Thank alot